# MagicalRecord not using my Model

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

I have my DataModel defined, I setup MagicalRecord:

```
 [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
```

I run my app and I go to browse the .sqlite DB that gets created (using SQLite Database Browser) and it has database structure, no tables, no anything - just empty.

How do I tell MagicalRecord to use my data model?  I don't see this mentioned anywhere?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the MagicalRecord.h file. There is a method called setDefaultModelNamed:. Or, you can call the method [NSManagedObjectModel MR_setDefaultModel:]. Either of these need to be called before you setup the core data stack.

Comment: do you know the default data model name that Magical Record uses ?

Comment: MagicalRecord uses the method +NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles to collect all data models in the main app bundle. This is fairly common for getting started with CoreData